# How to proper set HTML text in EditText view

Tags: android, kotlin, android-edittext

I'm having trouble formatting a text in an editable field correctly.
I would like to insert a textual field of type HTML because it contains for example "\ n". I am trying several scenarios but none of them seem to work correctly. In fact, the text doesn't pop up when it should.

Here is what I am currently experiencing:

```
        editNote.setText(HtmlCompat.fromHtml("first line \n second line", HtmlCompat.FROM_HTML_MODE_COMPACT))
```

The result is:

```
       first line second line
```

what I would achieve:

```
       first line
       second line
```

Comment: `first line \n second line` is not HTML. `fromHtml()` takes an HTML-formatted string.

Comment: I know, it was just an example

Comment: Use `<br/>` tag or `&#10;` instead of `\n` for htlm